# MySQL to Codeigniter Active Record to delete duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently in my Codeigniter site the following works to delete duplicates after sync with google calendar:

```
        $this->db->query("DELETE `e2`.* FROM `ea_appointments` AS `e1`, `ea_appointments` AS `e2` 
        WHERE `e1`.`id` > `e2`.`id` AND LEFT(`e1`.`id_google_calendar`,26) = LEFT(`e2`.`id_google_calendar`,26) 
        AND `e2`.`is_unavailable` = 0");
```

How can I express this in the Active Record format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('e1.id > e2.id');
$this->db->where('LEFT(e1.id_google_calendar,26)=','LEFT(e2.id_google_calendar,26)');
$this->db->where('e2.is_unavailable = 0');
$this->db->delete('ea_appointments e1','ea_appointments e2');
```

**LEFT() SQL:** get 2 parameter first field of table[like id or name...] and second parameter is the number of character from left of that field for example:

> Left(name,3)

suppose that  the name is equal to **hello word** than LEFT return **hel**

```
  $this->db->delete('ea_appointments e1','ea_appointments e2');
```

in this section we create **Aliases** from main table name for easy to use.

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.